# Can I output my sound to my Thunderbolt Display AND my Macbook Pro?

Tags: audio, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I work each day from a Macbook Pro, connected to a thunderbolt display.  I keep my laptop open so that I can have two displays at once.

From the top-bar settings, I have the option to toggle my sound to "Internal Speakers", "Display Audio" or a couple of headphone options that I have available.

I tend to listen to music through the "Display Audio" which is the Thunderbolt display.  However, I'd like to try and output audio from both sets of speakers (the laptop and the display).

Is there a way to do this?

NOTE:

About 7 years ago, someone asked a similar question about, but in regards to a Cinema Display ([see here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/can-i-use-the-sound-output-on-both-my-late-2009-imac-and-my-cinema-display)).  From this Q&A, the answer appears to be that this isn't possible.  However, this is updated technology and I'd imagine that there is a possibility that this has been changed.  Is dual-audio output an option on updated Apple hardware and os?

Comment: Not exactly a dupe, but identical scenario with same answer (yes):  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251357/is-it-possible-to-use-usb-output-and-audio-port-output-at-the-same-time/251360#251360

Comment: I'm not sure exactly if this is what you're looking for, but check out soundflower and loopback here: https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/